# Get array of strings by key

Tags: typescript, angular7

On an Angular 7 application I have the following:

```
var name_key = "name";
var language_key = "language";
var type_key = "type"
```

Then an API returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "language": [
      "language not found"
    ],
    "name": [
      "name not found",
      "name must not exceed 200 characters"
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to get the error messages for each `key` so that would be:

```
"name" > "name not found",
         "name must not exceed 200 characters"

"language" > "language not found"

"type" > NULL
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like that you need an array-like syntax allows you to access the object fields with variable keys:

```
const apiResponse = getApiData(); //your API response
const errorKeys = [name_key, language_key, type_key];
let errors = [];
for (let errKey of errorKeys) {
  errors.push(apiResponse.errors[errKey]);
}
```

P.S.: You don't usually use `var` keyword in typescript, because it messes with the scopes. Use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead, [here's why](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)